# Why does my functional code perform worse than procedural?

Tags: python, functional-programming, timeit

I am trying to count the numbers and words in a list using two different functions. They both generate the correct output in this case. But I always assumed the functional approach which uses list comprehension would do better than the procedural approach which uses a regular for-loop. When I use timeit to compare them, I'm not able to understand why the functional approach is actually performing worse. Could someone please guide me here and explain if there is a problem with my implementation?

```
test = [14242, 'A XUTFN UVG V UFI', 98, 80273, 'CKE', 'CPR']

def proc_counter(A):
    nums = 0
    wrds = 0
    for i in A:
        if type(i) == str:
            wrds += len(i.split())
        else:
            nums += 1
    return "Count of words = {} and Count of numbers = {}".format(wrds, nums)

proc_counter(test)
#'Count of words = 7 and Count of numbers = 3'

def func_counter(A):
    lst = [0 if type(elem) == int else len(elem.split()) for elem in A]
    nums = collections.Counter(lst)[0]
    wrds = sum(lst)
    return "Count of words = {} and Count of numbers = {}".format(wrds,nums)

func_counter(test)
#'Count of words = 7 and Count of numbers = 3'

%timeit proc_counter(test)
#1.15 µs ± 2.46 ns per loop

%timeit func_counter(test)
#2.26 µs ± 14.5 ns per loop
```

Comment: Because your functional code builds a list and Counter (dictionary), which takes time. Also it treats empty strings as if they were integers, which may be a problem.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny that doesn't seem to be the case. I've tried with a list consisting of 500 elements as well.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there can be no empty strings in the list (I've written a separate function to generate the lists)

Comment: Your second function has to iterate the list three times (constructing the list, counting and summing) your first function only once.

Comment: Additionally to Szczesny comment python is designed and optimized for imperative code and it doesn't ship with the means to handle immutability/purity efficiently.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thanks for pointing that out. I couldn't find a better way to use list comprehension for this problem. Do you have any suggestions?